# Samsung series 5 ultra - suspend on lid closing is disabled by kernel

Tags: kernel, suspend, samsung, acpi

I have a Samsung series 5 ultra (np530U4c - ivy bridge/Nvidia version).

The machine won't suspend on lid closing.

I has worked on fresh install. 
After it I added "pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1" to grub defaults.

After It the suspen not worked anymore. ...Neither with extra params nor without them.

I think the kernel switched off the lid closing detection, because it won't work on windows too.

How can i fix this?

---

My laptop bricked and the service changed the mother board so I got this problem twice.

Answer (score 1):

These kernel bug reports are related to your issue:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44161

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45461

According to the information in those reports, you can temporarily fix your problem by doing the following:

1. Power the computer down
2. Remove AC plug
3. Cut the battery power (it's a small hole on the bottom of the device, hold pressed for 5-10 seconds)
4. Plug AC power in before you power the device on

However, the problem will return next time you boot Ubuntu until those bugs are fixed.